# Xamarin Forms - Android - Can't get width or height of imageview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get the width of my imageviews at android platform. The width is "-1". I tried this in the OnAppearing() method. It's working fine at iOS platform.

c#

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    myWidth = imagePusher.Width; //Width = -1 at android
}
```

XAML

```
...
<ScrollView x:Name="scrollPusher" Orientation="Horizontal" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}">
    <RelativeLayout x:Name="rlPusher">
        <StackLayout x:Name="stackPusher" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
            <Image x:Name="imagePusherSpacer" Source="pusherSpacer.jpg" Aspect="AspectFit">
            </Image>
            <Image x:Name="imagePusher" Source="pusher.jpg" Aspect="AspectFit">
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
...
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can either subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeChanged/))

```
private void Image_OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // image size should be set here
}
```

or override `OnSizeAllocated` (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated/p/System.Double/System.Double/))

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called
    if (this.width != width || this.height != height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        // do what ever you like here
    }
}
```

Size should eventually be correct with either of them. **Please note** with the second method, you won't get the actual size with the first call. You may have to check for width/height being equal to -1.

Comment: thank you, but at OnSizeAllocated, how do I know when it is the view what I'm looking for, because no sender is given?

Comment: Or is OnSizeAllocated just for checking, if loading ist done?

Comment: You override `OnSizeAllocated` in your `View` or `Page`. You'll have to manually check if the size of your image has changed and is sound. There is no sender, no.

Comment: Mh it's not working. First time loading the view gets me circa 1735 for the width, which could be right. If I reload the page, then I got 0,4 width for the same view!? Whats wrong with android. ;O

Comment: there it's working now, but only at the second loading of the view,... strange.. also the height of my image is too high at the first load

Comment: The width and height properties are changed when layout is rendered, or when the device changes the orientation or when you turn off and turn on again the screen. It's calculated everytime due to LayoutOptions you are able to design. The `OnAppearing()` method are called before the layout is rendered, actually.